# Filtering out recursive directory paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

Given an array of files, how to filter out the paths that are children of other paths?

Example:

```
var pathList = [
    "/foo/bar/fooBar",
    "/foo/bar",
    "/foo"
];
```

A call to a function `parentPaths(pathList)` should return an array with one element `"/foo"` because both `"/foo/bar"` and `"/foo/bar/fooBar"` are children of `"/foo"`.

## Edit 1:

The function `parentPaths(pathList)` should return every path that either is unique or is a parent of one or more paths.

A more precise example would be:

```
var pathList = [
    "/foo/bar/foobar/foobar/foobar",
    "/foo/bar/foobar/foobar",
    "/foo/bar/foobar",
    "/foo/bar2"
];
```

Where `parentPaths(pathList)` would return `["/foo/bar/foobar", "/foo/bar2"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the array by length ascending and check if the string matches against stored strings.

If not match add it to the result set.

```js
var pathList = ["/foo/bar/fooBar", "/foo/bar", "/foo", "/bb", "/bb/a"],
    result = pathList
        .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
        .reduce((r, s) => {
            if (!r.some(t => s.startsWith(t))) r.push(s);
            return r;
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method..

```
function filterOutNestedPaths(pathList) {
   var result = [];
   pathList.sort().forEach(x => {
      if(!result.some(s => x.startsWith(s))) result.push(x);
   })
   return result;
}
```

**[Edited]**

If you are about to call this method in many places, you could simply add this function to Array prototype and call this like a built-in method.

Either you can make it return a new array

```
    Array.prototype.returnFilterNestedPaths = function getParentPaths() {
      var result = [];
        pathList.sort().forEach(x => {
            if(!result.some(s => x.startsWith(s))) result.push(x);
        })
      return result;
    }
```

or modify the original array itself

```
   Array.prototype.modifyFilterNestedPaths = function getParentPaths() {
      var result = [];
        pathList.sort().forEach(x => {
            if(!result.some(s => x.startsWith(s))) result.push(x);
        })
      this.splice(0, this.length, ...result);
    }
```

Usage :

```
var pathList = ["/foo/bar/fooBar","/foo/bar","/foo","/foo1/bar1","/foo1",   "/foo1/bar2","/foo1/bar2/foo1bar2"];

var filteredlist = pathList.returnFilterNestedPaths() // this returns a new array which you need to catch.
pathList.modifyFilterNestedPaths()  // this modifies the original list itself.
```

Comment: The solution would not work if the smallest path in the array is of an order larger than 1. Please see my edit for a better explanation.

Comment: Updated the solution. Thanks for reporting issue in it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
function getParentPaths(pathList) {
  const splitPaths = pathList.map(path => {
    return path.split("/")[1];
  });

  const parentPaths = splitPaths.filter((item, index) => {
    return splitPaths.indexOf(item) === index;
  });

  console.log(parentPaths);
}
```